# App Center Push notifications limit to 500 messages

Tags: xamarin, apple-push-notifications

In my Xamarin app I setup App center notification unknowing that there is a limit to the amount of message sent. Is there anyway around this? Would I be able to do it manually.

Comment: This feature is being retired - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/

Comment: @jason I also see that at this time there’s no way to Migrate

Comment: ms will provide instructions but no time when

Comment: You should probably switch away from AppCenter Push. Something like [Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/) would work nicely. It is not too hard to set up.